# Foundation 5-How to center position the class 'row' regardless the browser size?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

Currently in dekstop view, the body is centered and thats perfect. But when I resize the browser it streches to fix the full browser width and I dont want this. No matter how small or big the browser size is, I prefer the very first div that I used class row with to be in center leaving some space on the left and right. How to achive it?

My HTML is as below:

```
<div class="row" style="background-color:#072438;margin-top:20px;">

      <div class="small-12  medium-12 large-12 columns" style="background-color:#fbfbfb;margin-top:3px;height:30px;border:1px solid #ececec;">         

      </div>

      <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns" style="background-color:#ffffff;height:138px;">
        <div class="large-12 columns" style="background-color:#ff0;height:90px;margin-top:20px;">
            header
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns" style="background-color:#2D2D2D;height:47px;">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      body to go here
    </div>
```

This is the class row css by foundation

```
.row {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  max-width: 64.78rem; 



  }
  .row:before, .row:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table; }
  .row:after {
    clear: both; }
  .row.collapse > .column,
  .row.collapse > .columns {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0; }
  .row.collapse .row {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0; }
  .row .row {
    width: auto;
    margin-left: -0.9375rem;
    margin-right: -0.9375rem;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    max-width: none; }
    .row .row:before, .row .row:after {
      content: " ";
      display: table; }
    .row .row:after {
      clear: both; }
    .row .row.collapse {
      width: auto;
      margin: 0;
      max-width: none; }
      .row .row.collapse:before, .row .row.collapse:after {
        content: " ";
        display: table; }
      .row .row.collapse:after {
        clear: both; }
```

Thanks all.

Comment: Your .row is always width:100%. This should be because of its parent element, maybe some page Wrapper etc... You are probably using responsive grid or something like that.

Comment: I am making the site responsive. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change your main elements(pageWrapper) width inside your media queries. 
By default its probably something like {width: 1040px}. But after in media queries its width is 100%. Just change on maybe 80% or whatever you want it to be and it should work.

Comment: Thanks..Let me look for the class and try changing it.

Comment: I usually use it as #wrapper. It is telling you how wide is the page going to be, and it is already centered. Row isn't centered. Row should be only vertical stripe, with width:100% of its parent element (#wrapper).

Answer (score 0):

try to change the max-width of row which is to 80%

```
.row{max-width: 70%;}
```

You can keep it as much as space you want from left and right side this will work for all screen resolution

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking for there to always be margin left and right of the .row, and I found an answer to a slightly different question here [Zurb Foundation 5 - Row padding/margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24445475/zurb-foundation-5-row-padding-margin) that has an awesome JSFiddle - just update the margin to get the result you want.